# jQuery animate issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, smoothing

I've got some jQuery issues on my website and I don't have a clue what my problem is. Can someone check it please? Firefox has the most issues for some reason.

The animations are simple jquery animations, should work good, but it is not at all smooth on my browsers.
http://myfirstletters.com/base.html
http://myfirstletters.com/media/js/functions.js (animations are in the function start_animation and move_js)
http://myfirstletters.com/media/js/main.js

Thank you for your time

```
function start_animation() {
   $('#website').stop().animate();
   window_height= $(".intro").height();
   animation = ((window_height)*-4)-20;
  $('#intro_website').css('marginTop', -window_height-20);

  $('#intro_website').animate({
     marginTop: animation
   }, 17000,  'linear', function(){
     status=true;
     $('#intro_website').stop().animate();
     $('#website').css('zIndex', 1);
     $('#intro_website').css('display', 'none');
     $("#skip").css('display', 'none');
   });
}
```

Comment: you could paste some lines of javascript here

Comment: @faiahime, you are doing bunch of things in your functions. You need to highlight where exactly you are facing issues. Others can not help if you post entire js file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the intro animation after it completes (or when you skip it). The site will animate a bit smoother.

```
$('#intro_website').remove();
```

You should do it with all ellements that are not in the viewport. You can load them using ajax, when they need to show up.

Hope it helps a bit!